# Hyperledger install failure bccsp/factory/pluginfactory.go:12:2: cannot find package "plugin"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[Hyperledger Fabric install is failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY7Bc.png)

Comment: Have you installed golang?By the way the package is here:https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/internal/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/factory/plugin/pluginfactory.go

Comment: Yes, golang was installed.

Comment: Thanks for the package file, let me try with it. Cheers

Comment: Now i am getting.........import cycle not allowed
package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
 imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server
 imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/channelconfig
 imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/capabilities
 imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp
 imports github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bccsp/factory
 imports plugin
 imports plugin
make: *** [build/bin/orderer] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the wrong version of Go.
Fabric v1.0.x uses Go 1.7.5
Fabric v1.1.x uses Go 1.9.2
Fabric master branch uses Go 1.10

Looks like you are trying to build from the release-1.1 branch (the default branch), so you need Go 1.9.2.  The error is due to the fact that the `plugin` package was introduced in Go 1.8